# Can I pass a key combination through screen to a program?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

I've got screen setup to switch windows with the function keys. However, I am trying out Vim debugging and to start it I'm told to use the F5 key. Obviously this just switches me to screen window 5 (if it exists).

In my `.screenrc` I have the following:

```
bindkey "^[OP" select 1
bindkey "^[OQ" select 2
bindkey "^[OR" select 3
bindkey "^[OS" select 4
bindkey "^[OT" select 5
bindkey "^[OU" select 6
bindkey "^[OV" select 7
bindkey "^[OW" select 8
bindkey "^[OX" select 9
bindkey "^[OY" select 10
bindkey "^[OZ" select 11
bindkey "^[O[" select 12
```

This maps my function keys <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd> to screen window 1 - 12 respectively.

Is there a way for me to send the <kbd>F5</kbd> through to vim, essentially making screen ignore it?

Comment: What happens if you type Ctrl+A, F5?

Comment: Basically the F5 switched the window, and the Ctrl+a is still in the buffer, waiting for another command.

Comment: It might be helpful if you say *how* you "got screen setup to switch windows", and what your command key is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of literal escape sequences, give the termcap sequences:

```
bindkey -k k0 select 1 # F1 key
....  # to k9 for F10
bindkey -k F1 select 11 # F11
bindkey -k F2 select 12
```

Then, you should be able to pass them through with `C-a F5`.

Alternatively, add an explicit escape sequence that will have that effect. Fit escape, to use `^T`:

```
bindkey "\024" mapdefault
```

... and then use `C-t F5` to pass F5 to vim.